# How to randomly get item from string array?

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, random

I am trying to generate random questions from my String array called Questions. There 10 items inside. I am trying to set the text of  JLabel where once the button is click one of the questions from the array will randomly be selected and displayed. However these 2 sections of code doesn't return anyting.

```
public String getNextQuestion() {
    int NextQues = (int)(Math.random()*10);
    return Questions[NextQues];}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
     if(e.getSource() == Button) {  
Hello.setText(Questions[NextQues]);
```

Comment: `Hello.setText(Questions[NextQues])` shouldn't this line be `Hello.setText(getNextQuestion())` ?

Comment: I changed it to that but it doesn't do anything. It comes out as null when called to show anything.

Answer (score 0):

Don't hardcode the magic number `10` in `getNextQuestion()`. I would prefer 
`ThreadLocalRandom` over `Math.random()`. Like,

```
public String getNextQuestion() {
    return Questions[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(Questions.length)];
}
```

Then invoke that method in `actionPerformed` like,

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == Button) {
        Hello.setText(getNextQuestion());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling your method getNextQuestion

OK, you need an actionlistener on your button in order for something to happen. Something like

```
    public String getNextQuestion() {
            int NextQues = (int)(Math.random()*10);
            return Questions[NextQues];}


// inside main method 
...    
    Button.addActionListener (
             new ActionListener()
             { 
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                {
                   Hello.setText(getNextQuestion());
                }
             });
 ...
```

Comment: Even when I change it to getNextQuestion() nothing appears in the JLabel.

Comment: Drop us what Hello is and how did you initialize it?

Comment: Hello is a JLabel and I extented the JFrame in the class. I edited the question to include how i posted the Hello Label,

Comment: Run the Hello.setText(text) in a UI thread. That'll do the trick